# Como hago que la imagen cambie de tamano junto con el fondo rojo y el resto de cosas?

Tags: html, css

Por mas que lo intento no logro que el logo se reescale con lo demas. La idea era que la imagen se reescalase y que ademas las letras quedaran debajo de este todo el rato. No hay forma, acabo de empezar a aprender html y css y no se que hacer. Me gustaria que todo se reescalase como una sola pieza y que pudiera servir asi para cualquier dispositivo

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  color: #eee;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#headerlogo{
  float: left;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center 
}   
 
#nav-bar{
  width: 35vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#nav-bar > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 120%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <header id="header">
      <div id="headerlogo">
        <a href=""><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/elon-musk-1/128/_tesla_logo_elon_musk_-128.png" alt="tesla-logo" id="header-img"></a>

        <h1>Tesla motorsport</h1>

      </div>
      
      <nav id="nav-bar">
        
        
        <a href=#features id="nav-link">Features</a>
        <a href=#presentation id="nav-link">Video</a>
        <a href=#models id="nav-link">Models</a>
           
      </nav>
      

    </header>
```

Comment: Al tener un tamaño fijo el header, si algo dentro es más grande, acabará por sobresalir. Si quieres que el logo también se reescale, deberías añadir el atributo with al elemento de la imagen

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que utilices las propiedades que te brindas los servicios externos , dentro de tu html en tu head debes incluir esta libreria

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

despues puedes agregar este STYLE dentro de tu head

```
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.mobile-container {
  max-width: 480px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #555;
  height: 500px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
}

.topnav #myLinks {
  display: none;
}

.topnav a {
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: block;
}

.topnav a.icon {
  background: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

ahora para un menu como ese debes combinar js y css
para cuando se active tu menu puedas agregarle bien los atributos y los submenus

```
    <div class="mobile-container">
    
    <!-- cuerpo del menu -->
    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="#home" class="active">
<img loading="lazy" class="img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block img1" style="width: 69%; width: 50%" src="ruta" alt="Logo">
aqui puedes dejar tu imagen Logo</a>
      <div id="myLinks">
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
    
    <div style="padding-left:16px">
      <h3>Vertical Mobile Navbar</h3>
      <p>This example demonstrates how a navigation menu on a mobile/smart phone could look like.</p>
      <p>Click on the hamburger menu (three bars) in the top right corner, to toggle the menu.</p>
    </div>
    
    <!-- aqui termina el menu -->
    </div>
    <!-- boton que permite activar el menu -->
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
      if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

tal vez esto sea lo que buscas hacer...

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 20%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  color: #eee;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

#headerlogo{
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center 
}   

#headerlogo img{
  width: 10vw;
  max-width: 20vw;
}   
 
#nav-bar{
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
  
}

#nav-bar > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 120%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header id="header">
      <div id="headerlogo">
        <a href=""><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/elon-musk-1/128/_tesla_logo_elon_musk_-128.png" alt="tesla-logo" id="header-img"></a>

        <h1>Tesla motorsport</h1>

      </div>
      
      <nav id="nav-bar">
        
        
        <a href=#features id="nav-link">Features</a>
        <a href=#presentation id="nav-link">Video</a>
        <a href=#models id="nav-link">Models</a>
           
      </nav>
      

    </header>
```